# In NodeJS, are objects created during a request automatically destroyed once the request is complete?

Tags: node.js

If I create Controller and Model objects for each request received by a NodeJS server, are these objects automatically destroyed once the request is complete or must I manually remove them?

For example, if I have a router snippet

```
 
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    var authenticate = new Authenticate()
    authenticate.verify(req, res)
})
```

and in my Controller

```
 
Authenticate.prototype.verify = function(req, res){
    //perform verification and redirect user
    res.redirect("/some-logged-in-path")
}
```

once, the request is completed, does NodeJS destroy the created **authenticate** object?

From my understanding of other web technologies that use connections for each request, these objects are destroyed unless cached; so, I would presume that NodeJS does something similar; however, I cannot find any documentation about this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are these objects automatically destroyed once the request is complete or must I manually remove them?

Neither. After these objects become unreachable, which normally would be by the end of the request as per your code snippet, they become **eligible** for garbage collection. However, this does not mean the garbage collector actually runs after each request (it runs much much less frequently) nor that the garbagge collector actually processes the destruction of these specific objects on the next run (it runs incrementally, so sometimes it just does some cleanup but not all pending cleanup).

That being said, you do not need to do any manual cleanup (nor is it possible or advisable). Your above snippet is fine and doesn't need any special code changes regarding memory management. Garbage collection FTW!

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article on V8's performance engine, including garbage collection, [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/performance/mystery/). Both Chrome and Node.js use V8.

What you heard is correct  - once there are no more references to the object, it gets garbage collected.